# number of ways of writing an integer as sum of products

Tags: number-theory

As is well known that the  number of partitions of a large integer $N$ is given by the Ramanujan-Hardy discovered expression $$\frac{\exp(\sqrt{N})}{\sqrt{N}}.$$ However is there an expression for how many different ways to write down the same integer as a sum of products?

This would be a different answer from writing $N$ as a sum of integers, because there could be a degeneracy involved in writing each integer in the sum as a product of integers

Comment: First, the formula you give isn't the exact number of partitions, but an asymptotic estimate. Second, what exactly do you mean by a "sum of products"? Can you calculate the answer by hand for some small values of $N$, and then we could look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: Hi,Yes I am talking about asymptotic estimate. a sum of products is something like 6+ 10x3  = 36 which can also be written as 3x2 + 15x2 or 6+5x3x2

Comment: Are you asking for the number of partitions where no addend is a prime or 1?

Comment: Not really, but if you have an expression for that case it would also be appreciated.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking. Can $1$x$1$ be a valid product in your sums? How about $1$x$7$?

Comment: oh ok....i didnt understand it before....just products like 1x1 or 1x7 are not counted differently from 1 and 7 respectively

Comment: So, have you calculated it for small values of $N$, and looked it up in the Online Encyclopedia?